# Bootstrap 3 stack image in the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to stack the image on top of all the text, with the image on the same row with some text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery ui -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan='6'>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/search?q=professor&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS699US707&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=703&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUn_nPgJ3QAhUO7WMKHZjDD_oQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=MR0mBgD1-8vtJM%3A" height='170' width='170' style='padding-left: 30px;'/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>bob@example.com</td></tr>
      <tr><td>23</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Contact</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Party</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Start Term</th><td>2016.01.01</td></tr>
      <tr><th>End Term</th><td>2016.01.01</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Term</th><td>today</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Office</th><td>here</td></tr>
      <tr><th>State</th><td>CA</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Fax</th><td>here</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Birthday</th><td>today</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Social Links</th><td>here</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Please see my code in action at:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YgcNPhX8hc4HnNgZALBr?p=preview

The tricky part is the image is in the row:

wich takes 6 tds into one, and I want to stack it on top of everything using bootstrap3.

Please refer to the pictures to see what I'm talking about:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Define of top of everything! - on top of the page? on top of the table? on top of the row? - Side note: use `table`s for tabular data, `div`s for layout

Comment: You wanna use BS? Do that. Remove rowspan, and put col-xs-6 or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the plunker link as per your requirements. I don't have an account on plunker so my code will not be saved on the link. Here is the code for your reference:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type = "text/css">

  table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    align:center;
    text-align:center;
  }

  img{
    align:center;
    background-size:cover;
  }

  tbody{
    align:left;
    text-align:left;
  }

</style>
  <head>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery ui -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="http://www.google.com/search?q=professor&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS699US707&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=703&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUn_nPgJ3QAhUO7WMKHZjDD_oQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=MR0mBgD1-8vtJM%3A" height='170' width='170' style='padding-left: 30px;'/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Bob</td></tr>
      <tr><td>bob@example.com</td></tr>
      <tr><td>23</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Contact</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Party</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr><th>Start Term</th><td>2016.01.01</td></tr>
      <tr><th>End Term</th><td>2016.01.01</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Term</th><td>today</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Office</th><td>here</td></tr>
      <tr><th>State</th><td>CA</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Fax</th><td>here</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Birthday</th><td>today</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Social Links</th><td>here</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

I added css style selectors to get the effect. Also removed `rowspan` attribute from the `img td`. You should not need 6 `td`s to get the desired effect from your image. You can put it in one `td` in a row, and apply the `background-size:cover` property to stretch the image proportionally into a row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is going on with your tables in your html above, that's not bootstrap at all. Nevertheless, here is what you need to implement this layout in it's simplest form:

https://plnkr.co/edit/yK4MSDMA63P1n0roSgAW?p=preview

The html looks like this. it is essentially 2 rows of content. The first row is split in 2 divs, both of which will take up 12 (full width) grid places when the viewport of the browser is small, and 6 when it is medium or greater (that's what the `col-md-6` class does).  The 2nd row has a div with a column of class `col-xs-12`, meaning it will take up full width even on the smallest (phone) sizes. That should get you started.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://c7.nrostatic.com/sites/default/files/uploaded/donald-trump-bankruptcy-lies-r.jpg" style="width:200px; height:200px;"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet pancetta jowl filet mignon capicola ball tip jerky. Capicola t-bone filet mignon ball tip pork loin beef ribs bresaola pancetta shank biltong andouille porchetta ham hock short loin pastrami. Meatball frankfurter leberkas tenderloin brisket sausage salami ribeye ham ham hock andouille rump venison bacon. Drumstick tri-tip shoulder pork chop kielbasa tenderloin sausage prosciutto short ribs frankfurter hamburger t-bone chuck. Turducken pig meatloaf, meatball swine short ribs t-bone jerky. Strip steak cow boudin, sirloin leberkas pork chop frankfurter t-bone jowl rump tri-tip alcatra. Prosciutto meatball salami picanha pig.</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet pancetta jowl filet mignon capicola ball tip jerky. Capicola t-bone filet mignon ball tip pork loin beef ribs bresaola pancetta shank biltong andouille porchetta ham hock short loin pastrami. Meatball frankfurter leberkas tenderloin brisket sausage salami ribeye ham ham hock andouille rump venison bacon. Drumstick tri-tip shoulder pork chop kielbasa tenderloin sausage prosciutto short ribs frankfurter hamburger t-bone chuck. Turducken pig meatloaf, meatball swine short ribs t-bone jerky. Strip steak cow boudin, sirloin leberkas pork chop frankfurter t-bone jowl rump tri-tip alcatra. Prosciutto meatball salami picanha pig.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason I don't have my bootstrap code on is because when I had those code on, I get the responsive behavior I wanted on the iphone, but it failed to maintain the original layout on desktop.

Comment: @DawnZHANG Well, I don't know what you want then. The code above does what you require in your images. If you want to change the window sizes at which it stacks then you can change the `col` classes e.g. `col-sm-6` will keep the top row split to smaller sizes, `col-lg-6` will make it stack earlier. Good luck.